# Avoid bad Sphinx formatting of cement configuration

Tags: python-sphinx, cement

We're using `Sphinx` to format our Python documentation, and `cement` to configure our CLIs. Unfortunately, `Sphinx` generates a lot of nonsensical output from `cement` configurations.

I've been unable to find any Sphinx directive or command line option to ignore the cement configuration that it should not format. We're using `Sphinx 2.2.0`, and `sphinx-apidoc` with options `-f -P -o`.

E.g., Sphinx formats this Python

```
class BaseController(cement.Controller):
    """ Base controller for command line application """

    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        description = "Command line utilities for managing whole-cell model definitions"
        help = "Command line utilities for managing whole-cell model definitions"
        arguments = [
            (['-v', '--version'], dict(action='version', version=wc_lang.__version__)),
        ]
```

into this documentation

[image: noisy documentation]

The documentation shouldn't show the content of the `Meta` class. Can the Python be annotated with `Sphinx` directives to accomplish this?

Comment: The "noisy documentation" link does not work.

Comment: @mzjn: thanks for letting me know; fixed with `?raw=1` suffix on Dropbox link.

Comment: I don't know anything about Cement. What exactly is "bad", "nonsensical" or "noisy"? The output you get looks similar to this, from the Cement docs: https://cement.readthedocs.io/en/portland/api/core/controller/.

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation shouldn't show the content of the Meta class.

I presume that you have an `automodule` directive (generated by sphinx-apidoc) that looks something like this:

```
.. automodule:: wc_lang.__main__
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

The nested `Meta` class contains no docstrings, so it gets included on account of the `:undoc-members:` option. sphinx-apidoc adds this option [by default](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#envvar-SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS).

To exclude `Meta` from the documentation, remove `:undoc-members:`. An alternative is to add `:exclude-members: Meta`.

Comment: Did this answer help at all?